# Gmail Markup for Multiple Events

Tags: gmail, google-calendar-api, schema.org, google-schemas

I'm developing event markup using json-ld to be included with confirmation emails.

Some of my events are recurring at regular intervals.  However, recurring events are not supported by the latest Schema.org specifications so I've followed the advice offered here: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2011Dec/0062.html and decided to embed a json list of the individual events.

The json-ld passes the tests in the Email Markup Tester provided by google (https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/).

However, when I test the google calendar integration by sending the email to myself, only 1 out of 6 events in the series appears in my calendar (oddly, it's neither the first or last event in the list).

Does gmail markup support multiple events in the same email?  If so is there a better way to do it?

Example Markup:

```json
<script type="application/ld+json">
[
  {
    "reservationNumber": "7e15afb6b2485005e55481be58de4141b70f85006bd25823", 
    "reservationFor": {
      "startDate": "2015-05-09T16:00:00-07:00", 
      "endDate": "2015-05-09T22:30:00-07:00", 
      "description": "regularly schedule XXXX", 
      "location": {
        "address": {
          "addressCountry": "US", 
          "addressLocality": "XXX", 
          "addressRegion": "XXX", 
          "streetAddress": "XXX", 
          "postalCode": "XXX", 
          "@type": "PostalAddress"
        }, 
        "@type": "Place", 
        "name": "XXX"
      }, 
      "@type": "Event", 
      "name": "XXX Every 2 Weeks"
    }, 
    "modifyReservationUrl": "https://example.com/XXX", 
    "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed", 
    "underName": {
      "@type": "Person", 
      "name": "XXX"
    }, 
    "@context": "http://schema.org", 
    "@type": "EventReservation"
  }, 

  ...

  {
    "reservationNumber": "40553edbce52f0052e153919a4dad49ec32516c15433bf4a", 
    "reservationFor": {
      "startDate": "2015-05-23T16:00:00-07:00", 
      "endDate": "2015-05-23T22:30:00-07:00", 
      "description": "regularly schedule XXX", 
      "location": {
        "address": {
          "addressCountry": "US", 
          "addressLocality": "XXX", 
          "addressRegion": "XXX", 
          "streetAddress": "XXX", 
          "postalCode": "XXX", 
          "@type": "PostalAddress"
        }, 
        "@type": "Place", 
        "name": "XXX"
      }, 
      "@type": "Event", 
      "name": "XXX Every 2 Weeks"
    }, 
    "modifyReservationUrl": "https://example.com/XXX", 
    "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed", 
    "underName": {
      "@type": "Person", 
      "name": "XXX"
    }, 
    "@context": "http://schema.org", 
    "@type": "EventReservation"
  }, 
]
</script>
```

Comment: This would be great to know. I'd hate to send my users six emails when only one is needed. I wonder if using lists could work: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings or here: https://schema.org/ItemList

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this markup in the html file by using the Quick Apps script tutorial mentioned in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial).

Comment: I tried the quick apps tutorial (that's how I sent it to myself in the original post) but only 1 of the 6 events appears in my calendar.  If I send a single even the quick apps script method works fine.  It's for recurring events that it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @udackds I was able to replicate your result. In my test, I did 3 events and only 1 appeared in my calendar even though all 3 events showed up in Inbox. I'm not sure how you're creating your events, but it might be worth looking into the RSVP Action for your use-case: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/rsvp-action

Answer (score 0):

Does making a list help: https://schema.org/ItemList

Haven't tested this out, but it might be a useful approach.

Comment: Just for posterity, using `ItemList` doesn't seem to work either. The Google validator throws an error.