# How to fetch only emails that have schema markup like transaction ones using GMAIL API?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I have a ready C# code that filters email using some logic using GMAIL API but I want to fetch out the schema markup from the email that has transactional details such as order tracking etc and get the parameters....How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried looking up other SO posts or other blogs? If yes, please include your findings in your question so it will be easier for others to help you.

Comment: Hi, I already tried finding on SO and other blogs before posting and could not able to find it.
Looking to extract only schema markup from messages such as one in this SO post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905838/gmail-markup-for-multiple-events

Comment: Need to extract only JSON based schema markup from GMAIL messages instead of fetching the whole HTML data